# Python SUDS - Getting Exception 415 when calling a SOAP method

Tags: python, soap, suds

```
from suds.client import Client
url = r'http://*********?singleWsdl'
c = Client(url)
```

The requests work fine till here, but when I execute the below statement, I get the error message shown at the end. Please help.

```
c.service.Method_Name('parameter1', 'parameter2')
```

The Error message is :

> Exception: (415, u'Cannot process the message because the content type
>   \'text/xml; charset=utf-8\' was not the expected type
>   \'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"\'.')

Comment: any solution? Stuck with same

Comment: Darn, getting this exact situation as well...

Answer (score 0):

A Content-Type header of multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml" is the type used by MTOM, a message format used to efficiently send attachments to/from web services.

I'm not sure why the error claims to be expecting it, because the solution I found for my situation was the override the Content-Type header to 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8'.

Example:

```
soap_client.set_options(headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8'})
```

If you are able, you could also trying checking for MTOM encoding in the web service's configuration and changing it.